# Polymer, grunt-vulcanize: prototype.registerCallback is not a function

Tags: gruntjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a very simple HTML page with Polymer, which includes an HTML file with all the components I need:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/my-element.html">
```

`my-element.html` looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    // Some HTML
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        properties:{
            // properties
        }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

When I run it as it is, everything works fine.

When I try to Vulcanize the `components.html` file, and then open the same page with the Vulcanized version, I get the following error in the console

"Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function"

I have noticed the Vulcanize process turns

```
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        properties:{
            // properties
        }
    });
```

Into

```
    Polymer('my-element', {
        is: 'my-element',
        properties:{
            // properties
        }
    });
```

Which seems to be what is causing the bug, as window.Polymer only expects an Object as a parameter.

I am using [grunt-vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/grunt-vulcanize) to do the actual Vulcanizing, and my config looks like this:

```
vulcanize: {
    default: {
        options: {
            excludes: {
              imports: [
                'polymer.html'
              ]
            },
            'strip-excludes': false,
            inline: true,
            strip: true
        },
        files: {
            'build.html': 'components.html'
        },
    },
}
```

Is there a way of stopping this?

I am using Polymer 1.0, and grunt-vulcanize 0.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Got it: I was using `<polymer-element>` instead of `<dom-module>`. `<dom-module>` is correct for Polymer 1.0.

This guide is useful, and has taken me days to find, if only so that you know what works with 0.5 and what works with 1.0:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html

Answer (score 0):

grunt-vulcanize is not compatible with vulcanize 1.8.1, because last update on github was on Feb 9 with version 0.6.4. It's out of date plugin for Polymer 0.8+.

temporary adaptation for grunt-vulcanize which works with vulcanize ^1.8.1 and Polymer 1.0.
https://github.com/kgadzinowski/grunt-vulcanize/

just change in package.json:
"grunt-vulcanize": "kgadzinowski/grunt-vulcanize"

it'll work fine